# Firebase: query for best match results

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to run query on the Firebase DB and get the best match not the exact match

So I have something like this in the code.

```
// Create the ref people in the DataBase
    var people =   admin.database().ref('/People');

people.orderByChild("mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth").equalTo(mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth()).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                        console.log(snapshot.key);
                    });
```

This current query is for exact match, I am dealing with double values
(example of the value: 14.212670403551895)
which  will never give me exact match, but I want to get the best match. The value that is the close to that number, How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `startAt()` and then `limitToFirst(1)` to get the first node with the requested width or higher:

```
people.orderByChild("mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth")
      .startAt(mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth())
      .limitToFirst(1)
      .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

But that will never return items with a width smaller than the requested value. To get those you can do the exact opposite: `endAt().limitToLast()`:

```
people.orderByChild("mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth")
      .endAt(mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth())
      .limitToLast(1)
      .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

I don't think there's a way to combine these two queries.

Comment: It worked, now I have 14 properties which I would like to match against
this is only one.
Do I need to index all 14 keys ? and how about the query ? is there a limit to the number of values to match on ?

Answer (score 0):

By combining `startAt()` and `endAt()` methods of Firebase API you can restrict the result with the aid of an epsilon value.

```
people.orderByChild(...).startAt(yourMethod()-epsilon).endAt(yourMethod()+epsilon).on(...);
```

Comment: Not sure what -epsilon means .
Instead of eplison I did something like this with -5 +5 you know to give it a range.
I got an warning in the log.
FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth" at /People to your security rules for better performance. I assume I need to define it.

Comment: By epsilon I meant a small value to set a range. You used 5 for it. This warning is for security and performence you can check that out link below to learn more https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find all objects that have the child property that starts with the value of `mCalculateLeftEyeSizeWidth()`. Unfortunately, Firebase does not have much query functionality at this point.

The firebase "way" is to download the whole database, and query on that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference. It works OK with small datasets, but if you have hundreds of records, or if you need more power, I would recommend MongoDB or Parse.

Comment: Exactly. what I want is to get the Person that match these queries,
That is why I choose Firebase in the cloud :-)

Comment: Sadly, as I mentioned, it is not possible to do extremely powerful querying that you're suggesting with Firebase, at this time (July 2017).